# shoulda-callback-matchers after_save problem with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rspec-rails

I'm using shoulda-callback-matchers gem to test my callbacks.
But I have a problem with my `after_save` with `condition`.

Callback in the `model`:

```
after_save :update_effort_rate, if: -> { saved_change_to_rent? }
```

My test in my `spec`:

```
context 'callbacks' do
  it { is_expected.to callback(:update_effort_rate).after(:save).if :rent_changed? }
end
```

`Rspec` error:

```
Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to callback(:update_effort_rate).after(:save).if :saved_change_to_rent? }
       expected update_effort_rate to be listed as a callback after save if saved_change_to_rent? evaluates to true, but was not
```

I don't know what i am doing wrong. Any help ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the if clause by just passing in the method name (as opposed to a lambda that calls the method):

`after_save :update_effort_rate, if: :saved_change_to_rent?`

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#using-if-and-unless-with-a-symbol

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).